# Error with language pack using Magento 1.9.x and php 7.0

Tags: magento-1.9, language, php-7, language-package

Did anyone found a work around to install language package on php 7 and magento 1.9.x?

it throws me this error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Locale_es_ES 1.9.0.0: requires
>   PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1

using http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_Locale_es_ES

the official lang pack:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-official-spanish-translation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just download the zip-file using this downloader: [freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and upload the contents via FTP?

Comment: it kind of worked :), thanks for the link I didn't knew it, I don't use ftp, but uplodaded via ssh and git :D; I had to add the lang folder on translate as well

Comment: I face [same issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/206326/60631) with different version of php and magento. I have not choice than uploading the plugin via magento connect. Help required.

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems.

Comment: yeah, i used this unofficial link and downloaded extension.