# requires PHP version >= 5.4.0 and <= 5.6.32 current is: 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions

I get this error when trying to upload a package file via magento connect of a `Magento 1.9.3.0` installation.

`CONNECT ERROR: Package community/DynamicCreative 1.0.0: requires PHP version >= 5.4.0 and <= 5.6.32 current is: 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2`

The package file contains following specification as per the [system requirement](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html)

`<php><min>5.4.0</min><max>5.6.32</max>`

When I check `php -v` on the machine, I get

```
PHP 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Can anybody help how to fix the max version which can work across all php 5.6.x versions?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting `<max>6.0.0</max>`